# JSONStore push() gives "Data conversion error"

Tags: jsonstore, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using MobileFirst Platform 6.3.0.00-20141218-1823.

Using the following JSONStore push code snippet returns an error:

```
Procedure invocation error. Runtime: Data conversion error converting "{""FIRSTNAME"":""abcd"",""CONTACTNO"":9090909099,""ID"":2,""EMAIL"":""abcd@gmail.com"",""LASTNAME"":""xyz""}"; SQL statement:
delete from addressbook where id=? [22018-184].
Performed query:
delete from addressbook where id=?
```

The code:

```
WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).countAllDirty().then(function(numberOfDirtyDocs){
    if(numberOfDirtyDocs > 0){
        WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).push().then(function(){
            deferred.resolve(true);
        }).fail(function(errorObject){
            deferred.reject(false);
        });
        deferred.resolve(numberOfDirtyDocs);
    }else{
        deferred.reject(numberOfDirtyDocs);
    }
}).fail(function(errorObject){
    deferred.reject(errorObject);
})
```

How do I debug this to find a solution?

Comment: 1) Always mention your Worklight version and build number. 2) Edit the question and provide your application's implementation of said JSONStore push that gives the error.

Comment: Able to get the number dirty docs correctly, but when I try to push then I got the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was in my adapter code.  I had to

```
JSON.parse(input object)
```

in my adapter code.  Also I needed to use uppercase for the keys in the json object.